# Derivatives of the metric in the local Lorentz frame

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, differentiation, curvature

In the local Lorentz frame (local flatness at point P) we have:

$$
g_{\alpha \beta} (P) = \eta_{\alpha \beta}, \quad \Gamma^{\rho}_{\alpha \beta}(P) = 0.
$$

In the reference that I am following (The Mathematics of Black Hole Mechanics, Eric Poisson), he uses this frame to check the symmetries of the Riemann tensor, getting to the following result (using the standard definition of the Riemann tensor in terms of the Christoffel symbols):

$$
R_{\alpha \beta \gamma \delta} = \frac{1}{2} (g_{\alpha \beta, \delta \gamma} - g_{\alpha \gamma, \beta \delta} - g_{\beta \delta, \alpha \gamma} + g_{\beta \gamma, \alpha \delta}),
$$
however, to do so, it is necessary to make the following term vanish:

$$
\frac{1}{2} g_{\lambda \alpha} [g^{\alpha \nu}_{\quad,\gamma} (g_{\beta \nu, \delta} + g_{\delta \nu, \beta} - g_{\beta \delta, \nu}) - g^{\alpha \nu}_{\quad ,\delta} (g_{\beta \nu, \gamma}+ g_{\gamma \nu, \beta} - g_{\beta \gamma, \nu})]
$$
and I am really not sure why.

Comment: at the point $p$, we have $\frac{\partial g_{\alpha\beta}}{\partial x^{\gamma}}(p)=0$ for all choices of indices $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ (all $\Gamma$'s vanish at $p$ if and only if all the partials of the metric vanish at $p$, simply because Levi-Civita connection gives an explicit formula for each in terms of the other).

Comment: $\Gamma^{\rho}_{\mu\nu}$ is the linear combination of $g_{\alpha\beta,\gamma}$.  Conversely, $g_{\alpha\beta,\gamma}$ is also the linear combination of $\Gamma^{\rho}_{\mu\nu}$.  So $\Gamma^{\rho}_{\mu\nu}(P)=0$ means $g_{\alpha\beta,\gamma}(P)=0$.

Comment: To see that vanishing Christoffel connections imply the vanishing of the first order  partial derivatives of the metric, just use the metric compatibility condition.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Should I close this question?